# How to remove words that dont make any sense from a column of textual observations

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-cleaning

I have around 2 million reviews, most of the words in the reviews are pure garbage as shown below:

```
[('tcsworklife', 1),
 ('freshs', 1),
 ('elserun', 1),
 ('anathor', 1),
 ('ontract', 1),
 ('locationadibatla', 1),
 ('hindiname', 1),
 ('culturenegotiation', 1),
 ('ਵਭਗ', 1),
 ('ਵਗਰ', 1),
 ('ਭਰਭ', 1),
 ('ਬਹਤ', 1),
 ('ਹ', 1),
 ('ਵਧਆ', 1),
 ('happybcz', 1),
 ('qriruduif', 1),
 ('carpanter', 1),
 ('ghule', 1),
 ('intrapolitics', 1),
 ('collasan', 1),
 ('tcsthe', 1),
 ('oftion', 1),
 ('shiftit', 1),
 ('tellycalling', 1),
 ('majour', 1),
 ('securitied', 1),
 ('balaraju', 1),
 ('minupuri', 1),
 ('sdcvbhgvfcrdxs', 1),
 ('vgfcdxsza', 1),
 ('dscdc', 1),
 ('qdwd', 1),
 ('njn', 1),
 ('njnjn', 1),
 ('njnjnjn', 1),
 ('gbjk', 1),
 ('skhgksd', 1),
 ('kshdsgsd', 1),
 ('sbkhgsdjsg', 1),
 ('shkddshkjsd', 1),
 ('siddharthai', 1),
 ('nbwjh', 1),
 ('satilment', 1),
 ('mallinath', 1),
 ('tippanna', 1),
 ('djciajd', 1),
 ('fnjec', 1),
 ('jxrjcidcjtvm', 1),
 ('aporchunet', 1),
 ('thoraibakkamchennai', 1)]
'chooseeverything', 1),
 ('thatâs', 1),
 ('understandbest', 1),
 ('intercomany', 1),
 ('experiancelow', 1),
 ('anythingmachine', 1),
 ('lifetraveling', 1),
 ('timenight', 1),
 ('hollidayyou', 1),
 ('trsnsport', 1),
 ('workplacegreat', 1),
 ('webdriver', 1),
 ('freinely', 1)
```

How do I get rid of these words that make no sense and retain those that do make sense?
Note: some words do make sense but do not contain spaces, or it's just spelling errors and not garbage words like **weqwioeuwiouewq2rtg**. I am looking to find the most optimal way of cleaning this.

Comment: Thanks, but my query was also on how to correct the spelling, and spacing errors and take those words into consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare each of your words with the appropriate dictionary s.t.

```
import nltk   # if not installed yet just run pip install nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
if wordnet.synsets("Human"):
    print("this word belongs to the English Dictionary")
else:
    print("it does not belong to the English Dictionary")
```

to know if it belongs to a word in the English dictionary.

There are other possibilities with other language dictionaries if you need.